# DispatcherTimer stop when Window application hanged

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I have Written this function to update timer time in every single of second.

```
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0);

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            ApplicationVariables.ServerDateTime = CurrentDT = CurrentDT.AddSeconds(1);     
}
```

But if my application hanged for some time then application timer stop at that time and after responding application timer start and started from  last time rather than adding application hanged time with last time to show actual time. Please suggest me how to keep timer on even if application get hang.

I am using BackgroundWorker object to maintain application hang state.

It normally hang when my application trying to initialize object of fujitsu reader.

Please find attachment to more details.

[image]

Comment: The only real cure for crappy code that hangs your app is to stop using that crappy code.

Comment: Yup - like @HansPassant says, fix your GUI so that it does not hang.  Don't do hanging things in your GUI thread.

Comment: Thanx for reply but when i initializing fujitsu driver  object to scanning palm it takes 2 to 3 second because of that timer stop at that time and restart after completely reinitialize object.

Comment: Create/initialize/run driver from non-GUI thread so that it can block for as long as it needs to. It's the only clean way to avoid stuffing the form timer until the driver is done.  The only other approaches I can see are bodges that may, or may not work suffuciently well to satisfy your full requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using non-dispatcher timer to perform your task and update UI when necessary by invoking.

```
public System.Threading.Timer MyTimer { get; set; }

this.MyTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(MyTimer_CallBack), null, 1000, 1000);

void MyTimer_CallBack(object State)
{
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, (System.Threading.ThreadStart)delegate()
{
  ApplicationVariables.ServerDateTime = CurrentDT = CurrentDT.AddSeconds(1); 
});
}
```

Comment: Invoking hangs too when the UI hangs.

Comment: @usr True, but it won't delay the timer while that happens since it uses `BeginInvoke`.  The actual UI task will be delayed, but the timer will always be going on it's merry way.